# How to run thousand of json files as body of http POST request?

Tags: node.js, json, automation, jmeter, postman

So there is an API that is being tested in POSTMAN. There are thousand of json files that needs to be sent as body while making POST request to the API. Is there any way in POSTMAN or any other tool or script that can make this process easier and automated. Those json files hold the resources, each json file is something like this:

```
{
  "resourceType": "Bundle",
  "type": "transaction",
  "entry": [
    {
      "fullUrl": "12234",
      "resource": {
        "resourceType": "Player",
        "name": [
          {
            "family": "James",
            "given": [
              "Smith"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "gender": "male"
      },
      "request": {
        "method": "POST",
        "url": "Player"
      }
    }
}
```

With that post api request, there is cognito token, api key that is being sent.
In short how can I loop through multiple json files and put each in request body while making POST request at API URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [Directory Listing Config](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/directory-listing/DirectoryListing.md) plugin which can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager).

You can point the plugin to the directory with your JSON files and each JMeter user will read the next JSON file on each iteration.

[image]

Once done you can use [__FileToString() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) in the "Body Data" tab of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) sampler to read the current JSON file from the hard drive and set it as the request payload in JMeter

```
${__FileToString(${file},,)}
```

[image]

Demo:

[image]

Comment: For some reason it is only request and responding 1 json file out of thousands of json files. It does show 11k files in Test Directory Listing. In View Result Tree it only shows 1 json file in body requested and response data is only 1.

Comment: Try increasing the number of threads and/or loops in the Thread Group